# Emacs: Org-mode: How calculate duration of specific task?

Tags: org-mode

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

Suppose I have one org mode file. In this file I have my tasks with it's duration. After all my tasks was finish I calculate all tasks duration. I use command:

```
org-table-recalculate
```

It's work fine.
See screenshot:
[image]

As you can see the all tasks duration = 22.16 hours.
OK!

But I also (sometime) need to calculate duration of specific task
(e.g. **Task-1144)**
Here screenshot:[image]

As you can see the duration of task **Task-1144** = *3.50 + 0.08 + 3.50 = 7.08* hours.

So the question is:
How in Emacs I can calculate duration of specific task?
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not [ask the same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343542/emacs-org-mode-how-calculate-duration-of-specific-task) at the same time.  Please pick one or the other site.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one simple way of doing it manually.

The duration table is generated for you and it does not have a place for a record of individual tasks. Leave that table as it is and make a copy of it. Select all the  internal lines of the new table, and run `M-x keep-lines` entering the task name into it. Next, place the cursor last cell, empty it, and press `C-c +` to calculate the column sum and paste it in. Repeat for each task. Add free text to document what you have done.

If you keep doing this more often, you might want to look into writing a code block in your preferred language that processes the table for answers.

Comment: It's work. To much manual work. I want to use (for this task) built-in capabilities of Emacs. Without write custom script on Elisp.

Comment: You can not have built-in solution to your custom needs. This is Emacs so that you can create your own custom solutions.

Comment: If you want to know how to modify your process of creating the task duration table, you have to describe your current process and then ask the right question. Now you show the table and ask how to calculate something else from that table. That is the question I answered.